# cant get value in def function python

Tags: python, function, return-value

i have this script in witch i try to get the close of the last candle but i cant call the closePn value outside the def function.

when i made the code new it said i cant use closeP for calcutaltion bc of list error so i had to make it with np so i need to call the closePn value but i dont get any value.

```
import numpy as np
import json


symbol1 = 'btcusdt'
interval = '1h'

socket = f"wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/{symbol1}@kline_{interval}"

closeP = []
closePn = np.array(closeP)

def on_message(ws, message):
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    candle = json_message['k']
    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    close = candle['c']
    
    if is_candle_closed:
        if len(closeP) > 0:
            # remove previous close price from list
            closeP.pop()
        # append new close price to list
        closeP.append(float(close))
        # print the last close price
        print("Last close price:", close)

    
def on_close(ws):
    print('Connection Closed')
    
    
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket , on_message = on_message, on_close = on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

hen i made the code new it said i cant use closeP for calcutaltion bc of list error so i had to make it with np so i need to call the closePn value but i dont get any value.

i tried so many different sorts of code but i dont get any values.

Comment: You never use `closePn`. You define it, but then never use it.

Comment: \Right.  You're changing `closeP`, but that's an entirely separate object.  Either convert it to an array AFTER you have all the data, or use numpy to append new data.

Comment: you wont get any value because the `if is_candle_closed:` evaluates to false nearly all the time....  presumably you will get something on the hour mark....

Comment: @TimRoberts how can i chamge that?

Comment: You haven't shown us where you are USING `closePn` here.  Everything here is using `closeP`.  So, why not just delete `closePn`?

Comment: @TimRoberts i need the closeP value for calculations so i need to call it ouside the function if i just delet the closePn it still dont work.

Comment: Then why on earth didn't you show us the part that doesn't work?

Comment: @timRoberts because it is exacly that part because i will get nothing out of my calculations and why?? because i dont get the close price from the websocket outside that function.

Comment: In Python statements are executed in the order in which they appear. If you do `closePn = np.array(closeP)` at the beginning, and afterwards you call `on_message()`, whatever that call to `on_message()` does is not going to affect `closePn`. Unless of course `on_message()` is explicitely doing something to `closePn`, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found an answer so i just figured something other out. Thats my solution:

```
async def close():
symbol1 = 'btcusdt'
interval = '1m'

url = f"wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/{symbol1}@kline_{interval}"

async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
    while True:
        msg = await ws.recv()
        data = json.loads(msg)
        candle = data['k']
        closed = candle['x']
        
        if closed == True:
            closeP = candle['c']
            return closeP
                  
closeP= asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(close())

CloseP = float(closeP)
print(CloseP)
```